# Spring Integration with JMS and the conditional rollback of an XA Transaction

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

When processing a message over MQ I would like to conditionally rollback an XA transaction and have the MQ message put back on the originating queue.
Failures will be logged into the database and can be retried from the database using custom logic based on message type and error.
If we can't log the error into the database then the entire XA transaction should be rolled back and the message should be put back on the queue.
Each message gets processed over a number of steps and the code can handle the re submission/duplication of messages.

I have a solution but it result's in ugly configuration and I'd like to know if there is a better way to achieve the same result?
I was thinking of using a chain that ignores the message if its in error.
I hate that the service activator is not the actual service that gets invoked. Is there a better way to do this?

```xml
<!-- transactionManager is an XA transaction manager --> 
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="batchMessagesIn" 
    destination="batchQueue" 
    error-channel="batchErrorChannel" 
    connection-factory="batchConnectionFactory" 
    channel="batchMessageInChannel" 
    task-executor="integrationTaskExecutor"
    recovery-interval="10000"
    concurrent-consumers="1"
    max-concurrent-consumers="1"
    cache-level="0"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<channel id="processMessageFirstStage" />

<!-- The number of stages will depend on the type of message and this type of configuration will be duplicated multiple times -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="processMessageFirstStage" ref="messageServiceAdatper" method="processFirstStage" output-channel="checkIfFirstStageResultedInError"/>  

<!-- Payload is an instance of CustomMessage -->
<int:router input-channel="checkIfFirstStageResultedInError"
    expression="payload.inError"  >
    <mapping value="true" channel="messageInError" />
    <mapping value="false" channel="processMessageSecondStage" />
</int:router>   

<int:service-activator input-channel="processMessageSecondStage" ref="messageServiceAdatper" method="processSecondStage" output-channel="checkIfFirstStageResultedInError"/>    

<int:router input-channel="checkIfSecondStageResultedInError"
    expression="payload.inError"  >
    <mapping value="true" channel="messageInError" />
    <mapping value="false" channel="nullChannel" />
</int:router>   

<channel id="messageInError" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="messageInError" ref="errorMessageProcessor" method="handleMessageError" output-channel="nullChannel"/>

<beans:bean id="messageServiceAdatper" class="com.foo.messaging.MessageServiceAdatperImpl"/>
<beans:bean id="errorMessageProcessor" class="com.foo.messaging.ErrorMessageProcessorImpl"/>


<!-- this error channel will only be used for logging -->
<channel id="batchErrorChannel" />
<stream:stderr-channel-adapter channel="batchErrorChannel" append-newline="true" />
```

```js
public class CustomMessage {
    private Throwable throwable;
    private String originalMessage;
    private boolean inError;
    private Object payload;
}

public class MessageServiceAdatperImpl {

    @Autowired
    private FirstStageService firstStageService;
    @Autowired
    private SecondStageService secondStageService;

    //Don't let a failure rollback the XA transaction
    @Transactional
    public CustomMessage processFirstStage(CustomMessage customMessage) {
        try {
            firstStageService.processFirstStage(customMessage.getPayload());
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            customMessage.setException(e);
        }
        return customMessage;
    }

    //Don't let a failure rollback the XA transaction
    @Transactional
    public CustomMessage processSecondStage(CustomMessage customMessage) {
        try {
            secondStageService.processSecondStage(customMessage.getPayload());
        } catch(Throwable e) {
           markMessageInError(customMessage,e)
        }
        return customMessage;
    }

    private void markMessageInError(CustomMessage customMessage, Throwable e) {
        customMessage.setThrowable(e);
        customMessage.setInError(true);
    }
}

public class FirstStageService () {
    //Start a new transaction. Code also handles duplicate messages
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void processFirstStage() {
        //Do some work
    }
}

public class ErrorMessageProcessorImpl() {
   private static final Marker fatal = MarkerFactory.getMarker("FATAL");

    @Transactional
    public void handleMessageError(CustomMessage customMessage) {
         if (customMessage != null) {

            if (customMessage.isInError()) {
                try {

                    //At this point implment custom logic for logging message into the database. Message can be reprocessed from
                    //database with custom retry limits depending on message type and type of error.

                }
                catch (Throwable e) {
                    //At this point roll back the XA transaction and put the message back on the queue
                    logger.error(fatal, String.format("Fatal error attempting to save error", e));
                    throw new RuntimeException("Fatal error attempting to save error", e);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your logic is so closer to that `MessageServiceAdatperImpl`, how about to avoid such an overhead with Spring Integration (I mean `<router>`s) and just do `try...catch` and `if...else` in the code?

From other side you can code a custom generic `Router`, which just returns channel names by its internal logic.

Or... [`Routing Slip`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#routing-slip) since Spring Integration 4.1

Comment: Unfortunately we have to handle multiple different message types. 
There are several distinct services that some message flows will reuse but others won't. 
I'd also like the flow to be visible in the configuration.

I suspect I'll use a chain and won't call the underlying service if the incoming message is in error.
Its either this of use an MDB and wrap the call to Spring Integration in try catch so I can govern the resubmission of the MQ message in the case of an error.

Comment: That's why I suggest `Routing Slip` and see the next section there: `Process Manager Enterprise Integration Pattern`. You have just only the single central `RoutingSlipRouteStrategy` which desides where to send a message. Your config should be more clear.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I think I'll just call a service activator after message-driven-channel-adapter. This service will call a new gateway in a new transaction. If the returned message is in error or any error is returned then it can be logged. If this logging fails the service will throw an exception and this will cause the message rollback. There is only one slight break in the configuration and everything else will be a lot cleaner. Should have taken a look at this first. Thanks for helping me think it through.